# How to add required field validation on checkbox group?

Tags: angular, validation, checkbox, angular2-forms, required

I have 4 checkboxes in which at least one should be selected by the user. As I am new to Angular 2 so can someone please help me out in this?

Updated Code snippet:

HTML

```
<b><label *ngFor="let type of topics;let i=index" class="checkbox-inline">
                    <input  type="checkbox" id="{{'chkPhysician'+i}}" name="chekType"
                         formControlName="types" [value]="type.value" />
                    {{type.display}}
                    </label>
```

component.ts

```
public topics = [
{ value: 'test1', display: 'test1',selected:true },
{ value: 'test2', display: 'test2',selected:true },
{ value: 'test3', display: 'test3',selected:true },
{ value: 'test4', display: 'test4',selected:true },
```

];

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.mirForm = this.fb.group({
        date: [this.date, Validators.required],
        Name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]],
        Mobile: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)]],
        Email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+')]],
        types:'', etc..............
```

Comment: Hi Kiruba, please add the code you have so far so other users have some context for what you're working on

Comment: @amura.cxg I have added the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `change` event

```
<div>
  Pick your favorite hero
  (<label><input type="checkbox" checked (change)="showSad = !showSad">show sad</label>)
</div>
```

Or you could try using a [CheckboxRequiredValidator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/CheckboxRequiredValidator-directive.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems... if you want to have the ability of having several checkboxes checked, you need to actually have a form array instead of just a form control.

Then I would check that at least one checkbox is checked by a custom validator. So the build of the form should look like this (shortened):

```ts
this.mirForm = this.fb.group({
  types: this.fb.array([])
}, {validator:this.checkIfChecked});
```

Then you would have your checkboxes, and with that we look for click event and see if the checkbox is checked or unchecked. Based on these we either add a form control to the form array or remove the form control.

```html
<input  type="checkbox" 
        (click)="addRemoveToArr(type.value, $event.target.checked)" 
        id="{{'chkPhysician'+i}}" 
        name="chekType"
        [value]="type.value" 
/>
```

and the function:

```ts
addRemoveToArr(type:string,isChecked:boolean) {
  const types = <FormArray>this.myForm.get('types')
  if (isChecked){
    types.push(new FormControl(type))
  }
  else {
    let index = types.controls.findIndex(x => x.value == type)
    types.removeAt(index)
  }
}
```

and finally the custom validator which returns `null` if there is at least one checkbox checked, else return `notValid` error.

```ts
checkIfChecked = (control: AbstractControl) => {
  if(control.controls.types.length == 0) {
    return {notValid:true}
  } else {
    return null;
  }    
};
```

Comment: Thank You so much for your response. i am facing issue in checkIfChecked getting below error.file: severity: 'Error'
message: 'Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.'
at: '79,21'
source: 'ts'

Comment: Could you reproduce the issue in a plunker, since this code works fine for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/IOD3LUMWR7Wlb4uvv4Zp?p=preview :)

Comment: It working now with slight changes in code. however pristine/touched/dirty is not working for checkbox. can you please help me on this as well?

Comment: What changes did you need to make, curious, as we can see the plunker works well :) And your followup question is interesting. I have to take a closer look at some spot today when I have a little more time! :) I'll let you know.

Comment: Its not working in visual studio code editor. So i have added one line code as below.

 let typesArray = <FormArray>c.get("type");
        if (typesArray.controls.length == 0) {
            return { 'notValid': true }
        }

Comment: did you get a chance to look at it?